How to get reference to HTTP request inside a Spring Boot OpenAPI delegate?
I am trying to implement an OpenAPI spec using Spring Boot and the OpenAPI code generator. I went through whatever I could find online and was able to generate the OpenAPI stub. I used the sample spec at editor.swagger.io for the stub. Now I am trying to provide the implementation like this:
public class PetApiDelegateImpl implements PetApiDelegate {
    /**
     * POST /pet : Add a new pet to the store
     * Add a new pet to the store
     *
     * @param pet Create a new pet in the store (required)
     * @return Successful operation (status code 200)
     *         or Invalid input (status code 400)
     *         or Validation exception (status code 422)
     * @see PetApi#addPet
     */
    @Override
    ResponseEntity<Pet> addPet(Pet pet) {
      // TODO: fill out the implementation
    }
}

The problem I am facing is that I want to get a reference to the HTTP request in the method and looks like there is no way to get that. e.g.,
if I look at the stub [1]:
/**
 * A delegate to be called by the {@link PetApiController}}.
 * Implement this interface with a {@link org.springframework.stereotype.Service} annotated class.
 */
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-04-10T14:44:58.115530-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]", comments = "Generator version: 7.4.0")
public interface PetApiDelegate {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

it will just return empty request.
How can I get reference to HTTP request within my delegate methods?
